# Is there any option to add a series of numbers to SQL select condition?

Tags: sql

I am writing a select query but I need to filter the data based on a series of codes.
For instance codes from C00 to C99 or D00 to D10 .

Can anyone please help me to write the select where clause for this.

Thanks
Jude

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also explain what `code` really looks like.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you expect C123 code rows to be returned?

Comment: Please share table structure and sample data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your codes have a canonical format, then `between` should work:

```
where code between 'C00' and 'C99'
```

Note that this does a *string* comparison.  So these values will match:  `'C0000'`, `'C989999999'`, `'C57ABCD'`.  However, if the code is three characters with the last two being digits then this does exactly what you want.